# Will my graphics card run at PCIE x8 or PCIE x15?

Tags: pci-e

For example I have a 16 lane CPU, with a PCIE x16 graphics card and a PCIE x1 Wifi card. Does this make my graphics card run at PCIE x8 or PCIE x15?

Edit: My CPU is a Intel Core i5 7600k, and my Motherboard is an MSI Mortar Z270.

Comment: What CPU and motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your card would run at x8, because your CPU allows following combinations:

1x16 or 2x8 or (1x8 and 2x4)